# Sync AD Groups to Sharepoint Groups?

Tags: active-directory, user-profile-service, profile-sync

Is it possible or not sync AD Groups to SharePoint Groups means System Administrator created one new Group in AD then it is possible sync AD new group to SharePoint New Group.

next if it sync which Roles&Permissions assign to this Group please help me.
i worked User Sync but it is Group Sync.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard of this in SharePoint. It would be doable with some customizations, but not out of the box. SharePoint is designed to take your AD groups into SharePoint, and utilize them within security. It won't sync the members of a AD group to a SP group. That's a little redundant.

What's your requirement for this functionality?

Comment: Thanks for replay i searched but only Users sync available Butn't Groups.

Comment: Correct, groups are not sync'd since there's no real benefit to doing so. Sync'ing the user accounts help build out the user profile service, thus allowing users to manage their personal information, social, my sites, etc.  -- If my answer is acceptable, please mark off your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one circumstance in which you would need to sync an AD group to a sharepoint group.  It is a fact that a people picker can ONLY use a Sharepoint group on which to filter on.  If you have an existing AD group that is used for security purposes in a Sharepoint farm and also want to use this same group for a people picker control then you cannot accomplish that without some kind of intermediary customization (like the ability to sync an ad group membership to that of a sharepoint group.